# ajax javascript maybe - need advice

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

There is a table like this

```
text_ID(primary) | Text | Method 1 | Method 2
```

On my site I retrieve data from this table (text_ID and TEXT)

Method 1 and 2 are NULL by default. Users vote (their votes are stored on a different reference table like user_id, text_id, response, method_type)

Method 1 is a drop-down list like a SELECT with some prepopulated values 
Method 2 is an ENUM column with 3 choices.(both methods have same values available for vote for any text entry)

After vote period is finished for a Text Entry, I insert the correct vote_answer on method1 and on method 2 and make a backup check for the users that are correct (already did this)

What I want is every registered user to be able to vote on each entry of text only ONCE and only using ONE of the 2 methods. If a user already voted I want the specifix entry to be disabled for vote for him/her.

Any thoughts how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When rendering the page in PHP, for every text entry check if user already submitted an answer. If so, don't render the SELECTs with options, but some kind of message explaining that only one vote can be cast on each text entry.

Users won't be able to vote for the same entry using your page, but you still need to make sure that a second vote can't be placed by manipulating request parameters. Add similiar check (that the user hasn't voted for same text entry in the past) to the code that is invoked when user casts a vote.